# Is it possible to exlude some numbers from a range in python?

Tags: python

Example: Is that piece of code correct(If not what is the possible correct solution?):

```
for x in range(13,19)\{15,16}
```

Comment: I mean for x in range(13,19)\{15,16}:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following conditional generator expression:

```
for x in (n for n in range(13, 19) if n not in {15, 16}):
    # do stuff with x
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do stuff like this:

```
for i in [i for i in range(100) if i != 15 or i != 16]:
     print(i)
```

But I think in your case it's more simple to do this:

```
for i in [13,14,17,18]:
    print(i)
```

Comment: For better performance, in the first code replace the `[]` with `()`. You're making a list in memory, then iterating rather than creating lazy generator